# project shapes on 3d landscape using three.js

Tags: three.js, shadow, texture-mapping

My goal is to display a shape (triangle resp. polygon) on the surface of my 3d-landscape model e.g. to highlight a specific area in three.js. The landscape-height under these shapes differs, so I just inserted the shapes with a sufficient height on top of the "world".

It would be way better if I could display the shape directly on my landscape.
I've two different approaches for that:

- Create a new texture from a canvas with the shape on it. Then mix the texture with the actual texture of the landscape using shaders. I've no idea, whether this is realistic or not.
- Use the shadow of the shapes as projection onto the landscape's surface. Then I would have to find a way to hide the shape itsself, to color the shadow in the shapes color and to add a lightsource which doesn't skew the contours of my shape.

Will one of these approaches work out? Which one is easier or more recommendable? Or is there a complete different solution to achieve my goal?

Comment: I think you need to explain it a bit better, especially in terms of shadow projection. Maybe you could come up with a sketch or two.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is decals.

Comment: That's excactly what I've been looking for. Seems to be perfect for my case. If you turn your comment to an answer, I can close the question. Thank you.

Comment: Check this out for decals - https://github.com/spite/THREE.DecalGeometry